# Can't get active live streams from newer youtube channels

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Youtube API to look for active live streams on a given channel. It seems to work on some channels and not on others. It seems it doesn't work on newer channels and seems to work fine on older channels. I'm not able to find a cause for this. Does the channel need to be a particular age before this will start working? Or is it activated by views, likes or something else? Or is it a bug?

Using this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And on some channels it'll return the video on others it returns nothing.

For example I created a new channel to test this. I've been live streaming for 45 minutes. But the API shows 0 results.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCcMWekZ3Siq7KOWmNdM1hRA&eventType=live&maxResults=10&type=video&key=KEY

{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"ksCrgYQhtFrXgbHAhi9Fo5t0C2I/ZBV2w65lgyrdAoPQHuFS1_5SrKo\"",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 10
 },
 "items": []
}
```

If I change the channel ID to a different channel that's live streaming I get the proper result.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCCc1DMB-AcOssKJ7KweLXBg&eventType=live&maxResults=10&type=video&key=KEY

{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"ksCrgYQhtFrXgbHAhi9Fo5t0C2I/GWoy2_kaCrOSqfc467ecHDNOCdU\"",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 10
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"ksCrgYQhtFrXgbHAhi9Fo5t0C2I/AAjgW2-nA1kyQb7hAL0TERx3R_w\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "eNl1znfCYPw"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2020-03-21T10:15:22.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCCc1DMB-AcOssKJ7KweLXBg",
    "title": "TooToo Boy All Episodes | Videogyan KIds Shows | Cartoon Animation For Children | Live Stream",
    "description": "Subscribe Now: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCc1DMB-AcOssKJ7KweLXBg?sub_confirmation=1 TooToo Boy All Episodes | Videogyan Kids Shows ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eNl1znfCYPw/default_live.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eNl1znfCYPw/mqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eNl1znfCYPw/hqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Videogyan Kids Shows - Cartoon Animation For Kids",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "live"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I don't understand why. Any ideas? Is it a bug? A setting somewhere?

Comment: Can you give examples of each type of channel in your question, please?

Comment: Examples added. Thanks for the comment.